# Discord Music bot (Does not work but no errors)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I was building a discord bot which plays music with 2 diffrent files.
It does not work but there are 0 errors. Help is appreciated.

My main.py file

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import time
import music
from keep_alive import keep_alive
TOKEN = os.environ['TOKEN']
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$", intents = discord.Intents.all())

cogs = [music]
for i in range(len(cogs)):
  cogs[i].setup(bot)
keep_alive()
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Ignore the keep alive that works perfectly

And then there is the music.py file

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands 
import youtube_dl
print("Test 1")
class music(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client
    print("Test2")
  @commands.command() 
  async def join(self, ctx):
    print("E")
    if ctx.author.voice is None:
      await ctx.send("Youre not in a voice channel")
    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if ctx.voice_client is None:
      await voice_channel.connect()
    else:
      await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)

  @commands.command() 
  async def disconnect(self, ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

  @commands.command()
  async def play(self, ctx, url):
    ctx.voice_client.stop()
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options':'-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
    YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':'bestaudio'}
    vc = ctx.voice_client

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
      info = ydl.extract_info(url, download = False)
      url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
      source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
    vc.play(source)

  @commands.command() 
  async def pause(self, ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.pause()
    await ctx.send("Paused ⏸")
  @commands.command() 
  async def resume(self, ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.resume()
    await ctx.send("Resumed ⏯")

def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(music(client))
```

When i set this up, test 1 and 2 run perfectly but the commands never get executed.
I typed $join multiple times but nothing happened and no error popped up.
Im running blind here so i would heavily appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

try this and reply if working

```
    async def _join(self, ctx: commands.Context, *, channel: discord.VoiceChannel = None):

        if not channel and not ctx.author.voice:
            return await ctx.send('You are neither connected to a voice channel nor specified a channel to join.')

        destination = channel or ctx.author.voice.channel
        client = ctx.guild.voice_client
        if client:
            await client.move_to(destination)
        else:
            await destination.connect()
```

Comment: `destination = channel or ctx.author.voice.channel` i assume you meant to use a ternary operator? i am not sure that that is valid assignment

Comment: Didnt work, no error printed this time too.